# Sqlite copying table resources

Tags: sql, database-design, sqlite

I'm looking at using sqlite for storing some data that will be converted from binary to engineering units. The binary data will be kept as one table and the engineering data will be converted from the binary data into another table. It's likely that I'll need to occasionally change the conversions. I read that sqlite doesn't support dropping columns, and I was wondering how expensive (time, resources) it is to copy the old table to a new table, or whether I'm better off with a different database? It's preferable to have the database in a single file and not have a server running.

Comment: What do your measurements show?

Comment: If you haven't done so, have a read of [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)